# How can I set the scale factor for the android emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I know this question has been asked before, but the answers there are old and no longer valid.

I used to be able to set the -scale option to the emulator:
eg:

> emulator -avd device_name -scale 1 -verbose

But I see this in the logs:

> emulator: WARNING: The -scale flag is obsolete and will be ignored.

When I change the scale options in android-studio, it also doesn't do anything, because it is also trying to use the same -scale flag.

Is there a new way to set the scale factor?

The android documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html talks about the -scale option, even though it doesn't work anymore.

According to the emulator -help the -scale option is deprecated.

> -scale                  scale emulator window (deprecated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any command-line option that affects the window size. However you can press Ctrl-Up and Ctrl-Down to resize the window once it has launched.

Answer (score 0):

On a MAC that's CMD+UpArrow and CMD+DownArrow to resize the emulator size up or down, respectively.